# How to reference a nested generic type in C# doc comments

Tags: c#, xml-comments

In C# it is possible to add doc comments to methods. In the description it's possible to put a reference to another type using the `<see cref="..."/>` tag. When putting a generic type in the `cref` attribute I gather that I should use `{` and `}` instead of `<` and `>` in the `cref` attribute like this `<see cref="Expression{T}" />`. What should I put however if `T` is also a generic type? I tried `<see cref="Expression{List{T}}" />` but Rider is telling me that is a syntax error.

Comment: `Expression<List<T>>` is not a class name, what do you want the readers to see? Though there is no error using `Expression{List{T}}` in Visual Studio.

Comment: @shingo ReSharper (same creators as Rider) shows "syntax error" for the latter.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK currently XML docs do not support constructed generic types - [see this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/401). As workaround you can try something like:

```xml
/// This is <see cref="List{T}"/> where T is a <see cref="Action{T}"/>.
/// or
/// This is <see cref="List{T}"/> of <see cref="Action{T}"/>.
```

Comment: I was thinking I was probably going to get an answer similar to this.